# web/network programming with python

Tags: python, networking, web

Over the last month I have learned alot about python (as a complete beginner programmer), I built a text-based game and a few other beginner like applications. I'm looking to take that to the next step, with network programming and web development.

Looking through all of the questions I find the resources to be of a more advanced nature, and since I'm lacking beginner knowledge it's hard to follow some of the tutorials. For now my goal is to be able to develop web apps, including serving media, and having general functionality.

I've been told by many to use a webframework and learn the ropes form there, however I've found no interest in rounding off the edges of properly learning the basics. Can anyone point me to resources that will teach me the basics of networking (through python) and then onto WSGI basics (from a beginners standpoint)? I'd like to avoid using frameworks to get knowledge on how it all works.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't you start with the documentation? After that there are tons of tutorials on python network programming(including a couple of great books) and WSGI protocol.

http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html

http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/

Foundations of Python Network Programming covers all the topics you outlined in your question.
[http://www.amazon.com/Foundations-Python-Network-Programming-comprehensive/dp/1430230037/ref=sr_1_sc_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1329533527&sr=8-1-spell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230037)

Google is a wonderful reference to learn the basics of python network programming and the WSGI standard.

Answer (score 0):

[Google is your friend for this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_networking.htm), but if you really want to start at the low level, start with [sockets](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) directly.  Personally, though, my best resource for beginning to understand the more interesting reactions of networking came from [Glenn Fiedler](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/).

Comment: The Glenn Fielder site is a great resource, thanks!I will also checkout the official documentation.